# Regular expression to match an arbitrary length string of numbers, which may or may not be preceded by 0x

Tags: regex

I was wondering if you could help me formulate a regular expression to match the following pattern?

Any arbitrary length string of numbers, which may or may not be preceded by 0x.

Comment: BTW: If "0x" shows up in your number, then you might want to specify that the digits can be hex...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
\b(?:0x)?\d+\b
```

or this, if you want to exclude the optional `"0x"` from the match:

```
(?:(?<=\b0x)|\b)\d+\b
```

The former is:

```
- a word boundary
- "0x", optional
- decimal digits, at least one
- a word boundary
```

the latter would be:

```
- choose
  - either a position preceded by
     - a word boundary
     - "0x"
  - or a word boundary
- decimal digits, at least one
- a word boundary
```

The latter matches:

```
- 123456
- 0x123456
```

but not:

```
- 0y123456
```

To match hex digits (as your "0x" implies), use `[0-9A-Fa-f]` in place of the `"\d"`.

Answer (score 2):

Could you specify the question more? How do you want to use the match? Which language/regexp implementation.

A simple one that will work with many languages regexp implementations is.

```
(?:0x)?\d+
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the whole string to match (nothing else but the numbers):

```
^(0x)?[0-9]+$
```

I am using the class `[0-9]` here to be as portable as possible. You might prefer to use `\d` wherever implemented.

It works like this:

- match the beginning of the string: `^`
- match an optional "0x": `(0x)?`
- match one or more digits: `[0-9]+`
- match the end of the string: `$`

It gets harder if a preceding "0x" means hex number, and omitted means decimal number:

```
\b((0x[0-9a-zA-Z]+)|([1-9][0-9]*))\b
```

This also guards against decimal numbers starting with `0`...

Answer (score 1):

Formal regular expression:

```
(0x)?[0-9]+
```

Answer (score 1):

I always like to provide the very baseline REs so they will work on every RE engine, so:

```
(0x)?[0-9][0-9]*
```

With suitable boundary conditions (on old RE engines, that would be `[ \t]`), that should work everywhere.

However, it looks like you're wanting hex characters, if the `0x` is correct, so maybe you're after:

```
(0x)?[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]*
```

or it's equivalent in many of the other excellent suggestions for the more advanced engines.

Answer (score 0):

The `0x` you mention suggests you want to capture a hexadecimal number.  In that case I suggest:

```
(?:0x)?[[:xdigit:]]+
```

where `[:xdigit:]` is the list of all hexadecimal number in Posix notation.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you mean by a number, and in what context the numbers are allowed. I assume that numbers preceded by 0x are hexadecimal numbers and thus can also contain A-F and a-f.

Given this test string: `"a 012 0xa 4_56 num:8 42!"`

This regular expression matches `"012"`, `"0xa"`, `"4"`, `"56"`, `"8"` and `"42"`:

```
(0x[\dA-Fa-f]+|\d+)
```

This regular expression matches `"012"`, `"0xa"`, `"8"` and `"42"`:

```
\b(0x[\dA-Fa-f]+|\d+)\b
```

This regular expression matches `"0xa"`, `"8"` and `"42"`:

```
\b(0x[\dA-Fa-f]+|[1-9]\d*)\b
```

This regular expression matches `"012"` and `"0xa"`:

```
(?<=\s)(0x[\dA-Fa-f]+|\d+)(?=\s)
```

This regular expresison matches `"0xa"`:

```
(?<=\s)(0x[\dA-Fa-f]+|[1-9]\d*)(?=\s)
```

Answer (score -2):

\b((0x[[:xdigit:]]+)|((0|([1-9][0-9]+)))\b

Comment: The OP didn't specify that the string of digits couldn't begin with a bunch of 0s

Answer (score -3):

```
['0x']?[0-9]+
```

---

> This is more text to meet the 30 character minimum.

Comment: this will select a string containing digits, probably preceded by either "0", "x" or "'".

Comment: The first part would match either '0x' as a whole or not (the expression is in BNF notation. The second part matches a string of digits, or rather string of numbers. The presence of a delimited character is not mentioned, hence, would be an assumption.